# Validação de e-mail utilizando hide e show

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como faço pra validar e-mail e caso o e-mail seja válido, aparece um ícone de "ok" do lado do e-mail, caso não seja aparece um ícone "x" , caso não seja digitado, não faz nada.(usando hide e show) para esconder os ícones.

Comment: Mostra quando insere o email, ou quando faz o submit? Se for só um feedback por questão de usabilidade vc pode alertar o usuário usando apenas técnicas de CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz um exemplo para vc testar:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {   
 var valida = "teste@teste.com"; // texto só para validar a condição
 $(".fa-check").hide(); 
 $(".fa-times").hide();

 $("#email").on("blur", function() { 
      var input = $("#email").val();

      if(input == valida) {
                  $(".fa-check").show();
           $(".fa-times").hide();
    $(this).addClass("bordaVerde");
    $(this).removeClass("bordaVermelha");
      } 
      else if(input != valida) {
           $(".fa-times").show();
    $(".fa-check").hide();
    $(this).addClass("bordaVermelha");
    $(this).removeClass("bordaVerde");
      }     
 })
})
```

```css
.fa-check {
   color: green;
}
.fa-times {
   color: red;
}
.bordaVerde {
   border: solid 2px green;
}
.bordaVermelha {
   border: solid 2px red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="email">Email:</label>
<input type="email" id="email"> <i class="fas fa-check"></i> <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
```

Comment: Opa, valeu mano !!!

Comment: Se a resposta lhe foi útil aceite-á para fecha-lá no site.

Comment: ahh foi mals, sou novo aqui...rs

Comment: como eu faço pra ele já ir validando conforme o usuário digita? Por que ele só válida qnd clico fora...

Comment: É só trocar **blur** por **keyup**.

Comment: Valeu mano ! Salvou !